# Calling HTTPS URL with SOLR's DataImportHandler returns 403

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler, solr6

(This took me a while, so I'm providing the Question and Answer thinking it's worth it.)

The URL from which the DataImportHandler has to retrieve the data is secured via HTTPS and an additional `auth` parameter. The configuration of the `DataImportHandler` looks like this:

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="URLDataSource"
                baseUrl="https://www.gutscheinpony.de/"
                encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <document>
        <entity name="pony"
                pk="id"
                url="feeds.xml?auth=XXX"
                processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
                forEach="/data/offers/offer"
                xsl="xslt/gutscheinpony.xsl">

            <!-- fields omitted -->

        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Running this on a regular SOLR 6 installation will fail with a `403 Forbidden` code while a quick test on the same URL via `curl` succeeds (showing only the interesting output):

```
curl https://www.gutscheinpony.de/feeds.xml?auth=XXX -Iv
> Host: www.gutscheinpony.de
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Is it possible to set the User Agent for `DataImportHandler` connections without writing custom Java code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that Java does not set the User Agent by default. Neither do SOLR nor the `DataImportHandler` fix this automatically for HTTPS connections.

It is possible to set a User Agent value for a Java process using the `System` property `http.agent`. The value does only matter if the other server cares about it.

Thus, the `DataImportHandler` will run fine when SOLR is started like this:

```
bin/solr -f -Dhttp.agent="test/me"
```